# How to rotate a subplot in matplotlib freely

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation, subplot

I am currently writing a program where I can project a hologram video on my computer screen, I had written the code below and I do not know how to specifically rotate a subplot, I had created a 3*3 subplot and I need to rotate subplot 4 by 270 clockwise, subplot 6 by 90 clockwise and subplot 8 by 180.

Second question is how to get rid of all of the axis label... So that the hologram projected will be nice and neatly....

```
import pandas as pd
import serial 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200) # define the serial port that we are communicating to and also the baud rate
plt.style.use('dark_background')    #define the black background
plt.ion()                        # tell pyplot we need live data
fig,[[ax1,ax2,ax3],[ax4,ax5,ax6],[ax7,ax8,ax9]] = plt.subplots(3,3)     # plotting a figure with 9 subplot


Xplot = []
Yplot = []
Zplot = []
blankx = []
blanky = []
fig = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9]


while True:                         #always looping this sequence
    while(ser.inWaiting()==0):      #if no input from the serial, wait and do nothing
        pass
    data = ser.readline()           #obtain the input from COM 5 
    data_processed = data.decode('utf-8')  #to get rid of the unnecessary string part
    data_split = data_processed.split(",")  # split the incoming string into a list
    x = float(data_split[0])    #to obtain seperate float values for x,y,z
    y = float(data_split[1])
    z = float(data_split[2])
    reset = int(data_split[3])  # reset will output 1
    draw = int(data_split[4])   # draw will output 2

    if(draw == 2):
        Xplot.append(x)         #if draw is given instruction, add the x,y,z value into the list to be plot on the graph
        Yplot.append(y)
        Zplot.append(z)


    ax1.plot(blankx,blanky)         # subplotting
    ax2.plot(Xplot,Yplot,"ro")
    ax3.plot(blankx,blank)
    ax4.plot(Xplot,Yplot,"ro")
    ax5.plot(blankx,blank)
    ax6.plot(Xplot,Yplot,"ro")
    ax7.plot(blankx,blanky)
    ax8.plot(Xplot,Yplot,"ro")
    ax9.plot(blankx,blanky)

    if(reset == 1):
        for f in fig:       #if reset is given instruction, clear all figure and clear the elements in the plotting list
        f.clear()
        Xplot = []
        Yplot = []
        Zplot = [] 

    plt.pause(.000001)
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution, but not a perfect one, I use math instead of code to rotate the plotting, just multiple it by negative value to flip at x and y axis, I have also added a denoiser function to lower the deviation, here is the code that I use, if anyone had any idea about how to rotate a subplot freely, please enlight me.

```
import pandas as pd
import serial 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200) # define the serial port that we are communicating to and also the baud rate
plt.style.use('dark_background')    #define the black background
plt.ion()                        # tell pyplot we need live data
fig,[[ax1,ax2,ax3],[ax4,ax5,ax6],[ax7,ax8,ax9]] = plt.subplots(3,3)     # plotting a figure with 9 subplot

rx = [0]
ry = [0]
rz = [0]
Xplot2 = []
Xplot4 = []
Xplot6 = []
Xplot8 = []
Zplot2 = []
Zplot4 = []
Zplot6 = []
Zplot8 = []
blankx = []
blankz = []
fig = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5,ax6,ax7,ax8,ax9]

def switch(x):
    return x*-1

def denoiser(x):
    return (x[-1] +x[-2])/4

while True:                         #always looping this sequence
    while(ser.inWaiting()==0):      #if no input from the serial, wait and do nothing
        pass
    data = ser.readline()           #obtain the input from COM 5 
    data_processed = data.decode('utf-8')  #to get rid of the unnecessary string part
    data_split = data_processed.split(",")  # split the incoming string into a list
    rx.append(float(data_split[0]))    #to obtain seperate float values for x,y,z
    ry.append(float(data_split[1]))
    rz.append(float(data_split[2]))
    reset = int(data_split[3])  # reset will output 1
    draw = int(data_split[4])   # draw will output 2

    x = denoiser(rx)
    y = denoiser(ry)
    z = denoiser(rz)

    if(draw == 2):
        Xplot8.append(x)         #if draw is given instruction, add the x,y,z value into the list to be plot on the graph
        Zplot8.append(z)

        Xplot2.append(switch(x))
        Zplot2.append(switch(z))

        Xplot4.append(x)
        Zplot4.append(switch(z))

        Xplot6.append(switch(x))
         Zplot6.append(z)


    ax1.plot(blankx,blankz)         # subplotting
    ax1.axis("off")
    ax2.plot(Xplot2,Zplot2,"ro")
    ax2.axis("off")
    ax3.plot(blankx,blankz)
    ax3.axis("off")
    ax4.plot(Xplot4,Zplot4,"ro")
    ax4.axis("off")
    ax5.plot(blankx,blankz)
    ax5.axis("off")
    ax6.plot(Xplot6,Zplot6,"ro")
    ax6.axis("off")
    ax7.plot(blankx,blankz)
    ax7.axis("off")
    ax8.plot(Xplot8,Zplot8,"ro")
    ax8.axis("off")
    ax9.plot(blankx,blankz)
    ax9.axis("off")

if(reset == 1):
    for f in fig:       #if reset is given instruction, clear all figure and clear the elements in the plotting list
        f.clear()
    Xplot2 = []
    Xplot4 = []
    Xplot6 = []
    Xplot8 = []
    Zplot2 = []
    Zplot4 = []
    Zplot6 = []
    Zplot8 = [] 

plt.pause(.000001)
```